# How to fetch element locator for just labels?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]I have a web element whose HTML is written as :

```
<div class="tabsContent">
<div id="whenGetPaid" class="txtRight oRight">
<div class="oClearBoth"></div>
<section id="adjustmentsSection">
<h2>Other Payments and Adjustments</h2>
<table class="oTableLite oTableFixedPrice">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Pending</td>
<td>
<strong>Bonus</strong>
<br>
<a href="/d/contracts/14233120">c1 em16042211001803 - test:</a>
Bonus Offer
</td>
<td class="txtRight">$1,000.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr class="oSumRow">
</tbody>
</table>
</section>
</div>
```

I need to find the element locator for the text 'Bonus Offer' since there seems to be no tag associated with it, except the label.

I am currently using :

```
//a[contains(text(), 'em16042211001803 - test')]/../following-sibling:://[text()='Bonus Offer']
```

The part before the following-sibling works fine. I want the part after that.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: You can use Link text or partial link text to indentify it. ANd then use get text for the label. Put it in String and Display.

Comment: and how would that be?  because partial link text would look out for the link itself i guess. Can you show how?

Comment: please post source code form parents in which your td is

Comment: Webelement a = driver.findelementbylinktext("Bonus Offer");
String b = a.gettext();
print b then. Will it do ? Or share the code please.

Comment: @raj N ish : I have attached the snapshot. Please check my edited post

Comment: it will be helpfull if u copy paste the same here

Comment: please check my edited post

Comment: Can you tell me the site too ? where this bonus offer is?

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this should work-

```
//table[@class='oTableLite oTableFixedPrice']/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(text(), 'em16042211001803 - test')]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the code with the below xpath. Hope it should work.

```
//a[contains(text(), 'em16042211001803 - test')]/../preceding-sibling::br[text()='Bonus Offer']
```

Please let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do it like below it will work

```
This will print the complete text inside the desired Td tag

String LabelText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='oTableLite oTableFixedPrice']/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")).getText();
System.out.println("Text inside the td tag is  : " + LabelText);

// now extract your desired text like below 

String[] RealText = LabelText.split("test:");
System.out.println("label text is : " + RealText[1]);
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use the code snippet below:

```
  String cellText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#adjustmentsSection > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(2)")).getText();
  String bonusOfferText  = cellText.split(":")[1].trim();
```